# SlidingMenu and Android Studio

Tags: java, android, slidingmenu

I am using the latest version of Android Studio and I imported the SlidingMenu project but whenever I import it (com.jeremyfeinstein.slidingmenu) and write the following code:

```
private SlidingMenu slidingMenu;
```

I get an error: **cannot resolve symbol SlidingMenu**

I can only import com.jeremyfeinstein.slidingmenu.* or com.jeremyfeinstein.slidingmenu.lib.App because that's all I can see.

Anyone know how to import it properly and use it ?

Comment: How did you import the SlidingMenu project and add it as a dependency? Are you using Maven or Gradle for your application?

Comment: I fixed it by importing the source code and resources directly into my project. But when I compile, it complains of few missing values in dimens.xml and I also get the cannot resolve R error

Comment: check your imports - do you have 2 versions of R imported?

Answer (score 2):

1. Go File->Project Structure: Import library folder in slidingmenu as a module to your project
2. Delete android-support-v4x dependencies in the slidingmenu module.
3. Rebuild your project.